# Unable to install packages via yum in AWS, [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, epel

While install rpms via yum running into the below error in AWS EC2 instances.

```
sudo yum update
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
    epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                   |  16 kB  00:00:00

     * base: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
     * epel: dl.fedoraproject.org
     * extras: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
     * updates: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
    base                                                                                                   | 3.6 kB  00:00:00

    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirror.es.its.nyu.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu%2Blinux/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://ewr.edge.kernel.org/fedora-buffet/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://iad.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://epel.mirror.constant.com/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://download-cc-rdu01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirror.siena.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://fedora.mirrors.pair.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirrors.mit.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirror.metrocast.net/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://mirror.atl.genesisadaptive.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://reflector.westga.edu/repos/Fedora-EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for
    epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    https://mirror.csis.ysu.edu/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
    Trying other mirror.
    epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

    http://mirror.pit.teraswitch.com/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml 

does not match metalink for epel
        Trying other mirror.
        epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

        https://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
        Trying other mirror.
        epel                                                                                                   | 5.4 kB  00:00:00

        http://mirror.grid.uchicago.edu/pub/linux/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
        Trying other mirror.
        epel
```

Unable to install packages rpms and it tries multiple mirrors and fails eventually. 
This issue is happening from yesterday, it was working fine earlier, not sure what changed in repomd.xml file.  Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: Does running `yum clean all` help at all?

Comment: @mokugo-devops this error occurs even while spinning up new instances via terraform. And I tried clean and did a update, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's an issue in the CentOS package repository.

As a workaround, you can download the `epel-release` package manually and install it using the following commands;

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a wider known issue related to the `timestamp` property inside of the `repomd.xml` file differing from the `revision` property.

The current suggestion is the following:

- Open the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file.
- Comment out the `metalink` property.
- Uncomment the `baseurl` property.

After doing this either run `yum clean metadata` or `yum clean all`.

This should only be done for the short term, with this reverted once the issue has been fixed.